# Azure blueprint deployment, getting Resource ID of publicIPAddresses of ACR Cluster

Tags: azure, dns, azure-resource-manager, blueprint, acr

I have an Azure blueprint, which deploys an Azure ACR Cluster. Creating the cluster also triggers creating of the publicIPAddresses of the cluster. I need to get the Resource Id of that IP to be able to automate assigning a DNS/A record to that IP.

I thought about this output record in the artifact, which creates ACR Cluster:

```
"outputs": {
      "IPAddress": {
          "type": "string",
          "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', variables('publicIPAddressName'))).id]"
        },
}
```

, which as I thought could help me dynamically get that Resource ID, but it doesn't seem to be working. Can somebody point, what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'Full' to your reference() function call, which instructs the call to return all properties, including the id.

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource?tabs=json#reference

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you only want to get the resource Id, you just need to use the function [`resourceId()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource?tabs=json#resourceid), not the `reference()`. So the value of the outputs should like this:

```
"value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', variables('publicIPAddressName'))]"
```

Note that maybe you want to create an AKS cluster, the ACR is a Container Registry that stores the docker images and it does not need a public IP address.